# Live Agent: set Case Record Type in PreChat doesn't work

Tags: record-type, liveagent, pre-chat

I am trying to set some data in the PreChat of LiveAgent, and it works for every detail, except for the caseRecordType:

```
<form method="post" id="prechatForm">
    <label for="socialChatSubject">Chatonderwerp:</label>
    <textarea rows="4" name="liveagent.prechat:subject" id="socialChatSubject" placeholder="Max. 300 karakters" />

    <!-- Map the detail inputs to the Contact fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseOrigin" value="Chat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseRecordType" value="Social_Media_ORG" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:lvl_1" value="Overig" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:lvl_2" value="Smartlife" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Origin,caseOrigin;RecordType,caseRecordType;Subject,subject;lvl_1__c,lvl_1;lvl_2__c,lvl_2;" />


    <!-- Try to find the Case by CaseNumber (exact match) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="Origin,true;RecordType,true;Subject,true;lvl_1__c,true;lvl_2__c,true;" />

    <!-- Show the Contact when it is found or created -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />

    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="Case" />

    <input type="submit" value="Begin met chatten" id="prechatFormButton" class="button-blue" />
</form>
```

There are multiple options set in our Salesforce system for caseRecordType, and the option 'Social_Media' is the default option. In this case I would like to override the default option and make sure option 'Social_Media_ORG' is chosen in the prechat. But that doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You must use `Name` values, not `DeveloperName`. Which do you reference in your post?

Comment: Record Type Label: Social Media ORG  , Record Type Name: Social_Media_ORG  , Name for Case Record Type: Record Type  , DeveloperName for Case Record Type in the code: caseRecordType

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick fix by adding `caseDivision` to the PreChat.
It works now, but I'm not sure why.
And it looks like a bit of a dirty hack to me..

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseDivision" value="ORG chat" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Origin,caseOrigin;RecordType,caseRecordType;Subject,subject;lvl_1__c,lvl_1‌​;lvl_2__c,lvl_2;Division__c,caseDivision" />
```